# SSH not working with TortoiseGit and Pageant

Tags: git, ssh, tortoisegit, pageant

I'm currently setting up TortoiseGit on my system but there's a problem with the SSH connection to my remote repos.

I use git from my Cygwin installation (since I rely on UNIX commands) on my Windows machine. For handling all of my keys I'm using Putty Pageant, and for using them through the bash I installed a module called [ssh-pageant](https://github.com/cuviper/ssh-pageant).

When using the bash I'm able to work with my remote repos (since I'm starting ssh-pageant right after opening the bash console), but TortoiseGit is using my Cygwin's git module directly, therefore the agent doesn't get started.

E.g. shown error when working with TortoiseGit pull command:

> Permission denied (publickey).
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>   Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists.

How to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

When TortoiseGit is used in combination with cygwin (i.e., the cygwin hack is enabled), TortoiseGit pipes all git command through bash.

You could try to add `ssh-pageant` to `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`, so that it should be called automatically when bash is executed.